# Limiting device access to internal website

Tags: ipad, configuration, profile, osx-server

I need a solution for Mac OS X server (hosting an internal website) that will limit device access to the website. It needs to be a solution that will only allow certain devices, including iPads, to access the website. I was thinking it can be done through a configuration profile, but not sure how to set it up on the server side.

Comment: So, what is your specific question?

Comment: What is the best solution to do that?